# Xcode- how to set different bundle identifiers for different build configuration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

In Xcode settings's `Info` tab for project (not target's `Info` tab), I have 3 different build configurations, each with 2 `.xcconfig` files set up for my iOS Xcode project. [image]

I want to have different bundle identifiers for different configurations for better code signing management. Below are my general identity settings, info tab settings and bundle identifier settings under build settings.

[image]

INFO section-

[image]

BUILD SETTINGS-

[image]

**When I update the bundle identifier directly in general section, the value in build settings --> Product Bundle Identifier gets overridden for all the build configurations**.

Please suggest me a better way to manage this!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have already set up individual xcconfig files for each configuration. That means you can just add the bundle identifier key with the corresponding value to each build configuration / xcconfig file.

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.mycomp.hockey
```

You need to make sure that you do not override these xcconfig settings in your Xcode project build settings (the corresponding value should not be bold).

If you want to switch between your bundle identifiers on the fly you might want to create one scheme per build configuration. That way you can just select the corresponding scheme in the Xcode scheme selector (next to the build/run button).

[image]

To create a new scheme, just select `New scheme` from the scheme selector and choose a name, e.g., `MyApp [Hockey]`. Then edit the scheme and select the preferred build configuration for each step, e.g., `MyApp [Hockey]` for the `Archive` step.

[image]

You will notice that the bundle identifier on your target info screen will change depending on the selected scheme. Sometimes you need to switch to a different tab of your project settings and then back to the Info tab before the bundle identifier changes (one of many Xcode bugs).

We use the exact same approach for all our projects.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @JensMeder- Thanks for your answer. I am not using separate xconfig file yet. But sounds like a good approach. I'll give this a try. One doubt- when you have separate xconfig file for each scheme, what value do you specify in the general section --> bundle Identifier field?

Comment: Short answer: nothing ;-). Long Answer: What you see in the Bundle Identifier field on the General tab is actually the value from your build settings. Whenever you change the value in your build settings or an xcconfig file the value on the General tab will change as well. You can try it yourself by changing the bundle identifier value in your build settings and you will see that the General value changes to this new value as well.

Comment: Thanks!! If you see the screenshots in my question, I have different values for Product Bundle Identifier for different build configurations. But, the first value (i.e. com.mycomp.xyz) gets populated in general section. Is it fine?

Comment: If you follow the aforementioned approach with different xcconfig files and schemes then the value in the General tab depends on the selected scheme and the selected build configuration of the `Run` step in that scheme.

Comment: Ohh okay!! That sounds better now.

Comment: You said that it takes the selected build configuration from "Run" step. So, the value specified in "Archive" step won't impact?

Comment: Anyway, I will give a try for this xconfig method.

Comment: Well, the archive step will impact as well, but only if you choose "Archive" to create an app bundle for deployment via Product->Archive. There will not be any visual changes to the General tab. Xcode will pick the corresponding bundle identifier depending on what you want to do, e.g., Profile, Run, Archive, etc. . Therefore, I suggest to choose the same build configuration for each of the steps for a given scheme. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok!! Thanks for all your valuable inputs

Comment: Is there a way maintain different `Version` and `Build` string for each bundle identifier?

Comment: Bundle identifier on your target info is not getting updated depending on the selected scheme. I tried changing tabs as well. It is showing info of One scheme only irrespective of currently selected scheme.

Comment: Don't forget to replace your set of bundle id in project.pbxproj to PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)";

Answer (score 25):

Jens' answer was a bit confusing to me. All you have to do is add the xcconfig declared variable (`PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.mycomp.hockey`) to the `Info.plist` product bundle identifier field:

[image: Info.plist variable example]

Also don't forget to declare it in every xcconfig file. Enjoy.